# Compute $\mathbb{E}(\exp(r(W_t-W_s))\mid\mathcal{F}_s)$, where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

As said in the title, for $(W_t)$ a Brownian motion and $\mathcal{F}_s
$ the natural filtration of it. I'd like to compute $\mathbb{E}(e^{r(W_t-W_s)} \mid\mathcal{F}_s)$.

The only thing I can think of is to use the fact that  $W_t-W_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$, and thus $W_t-W_s\mid\mathcal{F}_s$ has the same distribution as $W_t-W_s$, that is $$W_t-W_s\mid\mathcal{F}_s\sim N(0,t-s).$$

But how could I apply this result to the above computation?

Thank you

Comment: This might be a homework question, but I think it would helped if you looked up what independence implies for conditional expectations.

Comment: @DavidHughes no problem. Thanks for the guidence! By the way, not a homework question. I just read http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Courses/251.spring04/Handouts/BM.pdf this note, and I don't understand one step of its proof at the end of the first page..

Comment: @DavidHughes from your suggestion, I see that $\mathbb{E}(e^{r(W_{t}-W_{s})}|\mathcal{F}_{s})=\mathbb{E}(e^{rW_{t}-W_{s}})$. This is obtained since $W_{t}-W_{s}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{s}$ implying that $e^{rW_{t}-W_{s}}$ is also independent of $\mathcal{F}_{s}$. But what should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is: If $X\sim\operatorname N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $r$ is constant (i.e. not random) then what is $\operatorname E(\exp(rX))\text{?}$ In this case $\sigma^2=t-s$ and $X= W_t-W_s.$

\begin{align}
\operatorname E(e^{rX}) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{rx} f_X(x) \,dx \\[8pt]
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{rx} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, \frac{dx} \sigma. \tag 1
\end{align}
So work on the exponent:
\begin{align}
rx - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}
= {} & -\frac{x^2 -2\sigma^2rx}{2\sigma^2} \\[8pt]
= {} & - \frac{x^2 - 2\sigma^2 rx + \sigma^4 r^2}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{\sigma^2 r^2} 2 \\[8pt]
= {} & - \frac{(x - \sigma^2 r)^2}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{\sigma^2 r^2} 2
\end{align}
Thus line $(1)$ above becomes
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-\sigma^2 r)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, \frac{dx}\sigma \cdot e^{\sigma^2 r^2/2} = 1\cdot e^{\sigma^2 r^2/2}.
$$
And now remember that $\sigma^2 = t-s.$

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer!

Comment: should we normalize as $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$?

Comment: @ProbabilityDumber : Fixed. $\qquad$